# SSRS Combine two value based on two dates on one X axis LABEL

Tags: reporting-services

Please can any one can help me? This is my question:

In my report I have:

**Chart 1:** in the axis I have 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018

The expression value is:

```
=Sum(fields!ao_amountparticipationValue.Value)*100/Sum(Fields!ao_amountparticipationValue.Value, "Chart1_CategoryGroup")
```

Now my problem is; in **Chart 2** I want to have value WITH scrolling 2 years like this:

In one X label i want to have this:

2012-2013, 2013-2014, 2014-2015, 2015-2016, 2016-2017, 2017-2018

And the value should be the average of two years.

Thank you

Comment: Can you return the begin year and end year in your data and group by both columns in chart 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom code to create the average of each couple of years

```
Dim oldvalue As decimal

Public Function GetAverage(v AS decimal) As decimal

Dim avgvalue As decimal

If  oldvalue = Nothing Then
     avgvalue = 0
Else
    avgvalue = (v + oldvalue)/2
End If

oldvalue = v

Return avgvalue

End Function
```

Your value expression should call the custom code with an expression

```
=Code.GetAverage( SUM(Fields!val.Value))
```

For the label of years couple you can use an expression like below

```
= Iif(Fields!year.Value = 2012,Nothing, Cstr(Fields!year.Value-1) + "-" + Cstr(Fields!year.Value))
```

Notice that because there is no average for year 2012 you should check if it matches the first year and set label to nothing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to use a code, i juste want the expression to find the value corresponding to ;
this is the table 
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dybqm.png)

I want to notice too that 2012 isn't a start year, it may be years before, so it should be a standard expression

Thanks you again

Comment: Replace the static year value of 2012 with an expression based in a parameter e.g. Iif(Fields!year.Value = Parameters!YearFrom.value, ...

Comment: That's done thank you, did you see the table that i put in my answer before, can you help me to think to any solution to build the chart?